# Libgdx InputListener touchUp

Tags: input, libgdx

I've added `InputListener` to my *actor* and now I want to check if `touchUp` event is inside the *actor*.

**Simple example:** I'm starting draging mouse inside my *actor* and i'm finishing outside my *actor*.

I though that `touchUp` event will start only if mouse is inside my *actor* but it also start outside my *actor* (when `touchDown` event start inside my *actor*).

How to check if `touchUp` event is inside my *actor* only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two solutions here:

1. To use some flag to check if the pointer is inside the actor and handle it with **exit** method:

   ```
   image.addListener(new InputListener(){
       boolean touched = false;
       @Override
       public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button)
       {
           touched = true;

           System.out.println("TOUCH DOWN");
           return true;
       }

       @Override
       public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button)
       {
           if(touched) 
           {
               touched = false;
               System.out.println("TOUCH UP");
           }
       }

       @Override
       public void exit(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, Actor toActor)
       {
           touched = false;
       }

   });
   ```
2. To check if pointer is inside the actor **inside touchUp**

   ```
   @Override
       public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button)
       {
           Stage stage = event.getTarget().getStage();
           Vector2 mouse = stage.screenToStageCoordinates( new Vector2(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY()) );

           if(stage.hit(mouse.x, mouse.y, true) == event.getTarget()) 
           {
               System.out.println("TOUCH UP");
           }
       }
   ```

Both solutions need some extra code but both should be working fine.

Comment: The second solution all what I need :)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry miss read your question noticed when you changed it.

Still, I would add a listener and simply check coordinates of actor. The x and y given with a clicklistener just return local coordinates of the actor so a simple check vs width and height is enough.

```
    ClickListener cl = new ClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            super.touchUp(event, x, y, pointer, button);
            if (x > 0 && y > 0 && x < getWidth() && y < getHeight())
            {
                System.out.println("Released within actor");
            }
        }
    };

actor.addListener(cl);
```